# Remove space between two rows of small buttons in a table

Tags: html, css

All solutions that I have found helped when I use buttons which size more than ~25px and I have no spaces between rows. However when I'm trying to use buttons which size less (like 18 px) spaces between rows appear. So far only margin: -px helped me reduce spaces a bit.

```html
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; display: block;">
  <tr style="padding: 0;">
    <td style="padding: 0;">
    </td>
    <td style="padding: 0;">
      <button style="background-color:blue; width: 18px; height: 18px; border: 0; margin-top: -16px; margin-bottom: -16px; font-size: 0pt;" />
    </td>
    <td style="padding: 0;">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="padding: 0;">
    <td style="padding: 0;">
      <button style="background-color:blue; width: 18px; height: 18px; border: 0; margin-top: -16px; margin-bottom: -16px; font-size: 0pt;" />
    </td>
    <td style="padding: 0;">
      <button style="background-color:blue; width: 18px; height: 18px; border: 0; margin-top: -16px; margin-bottom: -16px; font-size: 0pt;" />
    </td>
    <td style="padding: 0;">
      <button style="background-color:blue; width: 18px; height: 18px; border: 0; margin-top: -16px; margin-bottom: -16px; font-size: 0pt;" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="padding: 0;">
    <td style="padding: 0;">
      <button style="background-color:blue; width: 18px; height: 18px; border: 0; margin-top: -16px; margin-bottom: -16px; font-size: 0pt;" />
    </td>
    <td style="padding: 0;">
      <button style="background-color:blue; width: 18px; height: 18px; border: 0; margin-top: -16px; margin-bottom: -16px; font-size: 0pt;" />
    </td>
    <td style="padding: 0;">
      <button style="background-color:blue; width: 18px; height: 18px; border: 0; margin-top: -16px; margin-bottom: -16px; font-size: 0pt;" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="padding: 0;">
    <td style="padding: 0;">
      <button style="background-color:blue; width: 18px; height: 18px; border: 0; margin-top: -16px; margin-bottom: -16px; font-size: 0pt;" />
    </td>
    <td style="padding: 0;">
      <button style="background-color:blue; width: 18px; height: 18px; border: 0; margin-top: -16px; margin-bottom: -16px; font-size: 0pt;" />
    </td>
    <td style="padding: 0;">
      <button style="background-color:blue; width: 18px; height: 18px; border: 0; margin-top: -16px; margin-bottom: -16px; font-size: 0pt;" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[image: screen]

Comment: Please tell me you didn't hard-code every single line of that.

Comment: As far as I can see there is no space between the buttons... can you clarify what the issue is?

Comment: I did hard-code because have found on few resourses that I need to do that and there are white lines between every row. I need to remove them.

Comment: Whew. Talk about keyboard pounding. [This](https://monosnap.com/file/4SjHpiV1rLp1UwdttRls8uWiaVDMCb) is what it looks like for me, I can't see any white lines. I'm using Chrome 71 on MacOS Mojave.

Comment: Then that's even more strange. I have put an image under code that shows what I'm getting and what I want to get. I'm using Chrome on PC. Why are our results different? I have made a totally new almost empty project in visual studio and added code above.

Comment: Just tested it in FF and it showed the white lines. Strange, but whatever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


<title>Untitled</title>
<style>td {line-height: 18px;}</style>

</head>
<body>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; display: block;">
  <tr style="padding: 0;">
    <td style="padding: 0;">
    </td>
    <td style="padding: 0;">
      <button style="background-color:blue; width: 18px; height: 18px; border: 0; margin-top: -16px; margin-bottom: -16px; font-size: 0pt;" />
    </td>
    <td style="padding: 0;">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="padding: 0;">
    <td style="padding: 0;">
      <button style="background-color:blue; width: 18px; height: 18px; border: 0; margin-top: -16px; margin-bottom: -16px; font-size: 0pt;" />
    </td>
    <td style="padding: 0;">
      <button style="background-color:blue; width: 18px; height: 18px; border: 0; margin-top: -16px; margin-bottom: -16px; font-size: 0pt;" />
    </td>
    <td style="padding: 0;">
      <button style="background-color:blue; width: 18px; height: 18px; border: 0; margin-top: -16px; margin-bottom: -16px; font-size: 0pt;" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="padding: 0;">
    <td style="padding: 0;">
      <button style="background-color:blue; width: 18px; height: 18px; border: 0; margin-top: -16px; margin-bottom: -16px; font-size: 0pt;" />
    </td>
    <td style="padding: 0;">
      <button style="background-color:blue; width: 18px; height: 18px; border: 0; margin-top: -16px; margin-bottom: -16px; font-size: 0pt;" />
    </td>
    <td style="padding: 0;">
      <button style="background-color:blue; width: 18px; height: 18px; border: 0; margin-top: -16px; margin-bottom: -16px; font-size: 0pt;" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="padding: 0;">
    <td style="padding: 0;">
      <button style="background-color:blue; width: 18px; height: 18px; border: 0; margin-top: -16px; margin-bottom: -16px; font-size: 0pt;" />
    </td>
    <td style="padding: 0;">
      <button style="background-color:blue; width: 18px; height: 18px; border: 0; margin-top: -16px; margin-bottom: -16px; font-size: 0pt;" />
    </td>
    <td style="padding: 0;">
      <button style="background-color:blue; width: 18px; height: 18px; border: 0; margin-top: -16px; margin-bottom: -16px; font-size: 0pt;" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That works. After some testing I have found that problem in line
<webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" />
That line is creating for every web form project in c# asp.net visual studio. If I totally delete that line then many things stop work unfortunatelly

Comment: Checked your answer again after edit and added line-height:18px for every td and that works perfect! (I cant add totally new style since I have another table and I need another line-height for them). Thank you very much